# How to insert value from a list into other at position of space?

Tags: python

these are my lists

```
i=["abc","def","ghi"]
j=[" ","rfd"," "," ","qf"]
```

and i want my output be like this,

```
j=["abc","rfd","def","ghi","qf"]
```

i.e, whenever it finds spaces inside "j",it should replace space by a element from "i"?
How to insert value from a list into other at position of space

Comment: Those aren't empty strings. They are spaces

Comment: ya, my bad..., thats what, spaces..! ty..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice and easy solution to understand:

```
>>> i = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
>>> j = [' ', 'rfd', ' ', ' ', 'qf']
>>> cnt = 0
>>> new = []
>>> for item in j:
...     if item == ' ':
...             new.append(i[cnt])
...             cnt += 1
...     else:
...             new.append(item)
... 
>>> print new
['abc', 'rfd', 'abc', 'abc', 'qf']
```

Comment: You forgot to increment `cnt`

Comment: @Kos Oops... so i did

Answer (score 4):

```
it= iter(i)
[next(it) if item.isspace() else item for item in j]
```

This will iterate through the `j` list and yield the element if it's not "empty" (all whitespace). If it is "empty", it will yield the next element of the `i` list.

*Thanks to @JonClements and @DSM for suggestions.*

Comment: `next(it)` is fine from Python 2.6 and should be preferred

Comment: There's also `.isspace()`, which I think looks a little cleaner.

Comment: @DSM True, changed it.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
i=["abc","def","ghi"]
j=[" ","rfd"," "," ","qf"]

filler = iter(i)
print [el if el != ' ' else next(filler, ' ') for el in j]
# ['abc', 'rfd', 'def', 'ghi', 'qf']
```

Take off the default parameter (eg: `next(filler)`) if an exception should occur where there's a space in `j` but no further replacements available from `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not a very common problem:

```
i=["abc","def","ghi"]
j=[" ","rfd"," "," ","qf"]


while " " in j and i:
    j[j.index(" ")] = i.pop(0)

print j
Output: ['abc', 'rfd', 'def', 'ghi', 'qf']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[x for x in (i + j) if len(x.strip()) > 0]
```

Simple solution using list comprehension.

Comment: This won't fill in the spaces on `j` with elements from `i`... It's effectively a filter on the concatenated lists...